# pandas merge to bring two columns from a dataframe and doing operations on column

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table in pandas dataframe  df

```
Leafid  pidx  pidy  value
  100     1     3      10
  100     2     6      12
  200     5     7      48
  300     7     1      11
```

i have another dataframe df2 which has

```
pid  price
1      10
2      20
3      30
4      40
5      50
6      60
7      70
```

i want to merge df and df2 such that i have two more column's `price_pidx and price_pidy`

and then also do division of `price_pidy/price_pidx`

for example:

`Leafid  pidx   pidy  value    price_pidx    price_pidy    price_pidy/price_pidx`

```
 `100    1      3     10            10           30             3`
```

my final df should have columns

```
pidx   pidy   value   price_pidx/price_pidy
```

i don't want to use `.map()` in this.
is there any way to do it using `pd.merge`?

i know how to bring one column `price_pidx` but how to bring both?

for eg.

```
pd.merge(df,df2['pid','price'],how = left, left_on = 'pidx' right_on = 'pid')
```

but how to bring both price_pidx and price_pidy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `map` it is complicated, because need reshape by [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html), then `merge` and last [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='value', value_name='pid', var_name='g')
df2 = pd.merge(df,df2[['pid','price']], how='left', on = 'pid')
df2 = df2.set_index(['value','g']).unstack()
df2.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df2.columns]
df2['col'] = df2.price_pidy / df2.price_pidx
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'pid_pidx':'pidx','pid_pidy':'pidy'})
print (df2)
       pidx  pidy  price_pidx  price_pidy       col
value                                              
10        1     3          10          30  3.000000
11        7     1          70          10  0.142857
12        2     6          20          60  3.000000
48        5     7          50          70  1.400000
```

Comment: for a huge dataframe, would map work faster or merge for this problem.?

Comment: map is win ;) becuase no reshape is need.

Comment: if my df has one more column say `Leafid` do i have to add it in `id_vars`

Comment: df = pd.melt(df, id_vars1='value',id_vars2='Leafid' value_name='pid', var_name='g')

Comment: Hmmm, unfortunately `id_vars1` is not parameter, only `id_vars`

Comment: You need change `df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['value','Leafid'], value_name='pid', var_name='g')` and `df2 = df2.set_index(['Leafid','value','g']).unstack()`.